# live unwrap missing form 3d viewport options

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm in blender 2.91.0 and in the 3d viewport UV menu the live unwrap option is missing.[image]

any opinions?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like there are 2 *Live Unwrap*.

The first one is in the *Options* or in the *N panel > Tool > Options*, it will automatically refresh the UV map whenever you change the seams of the object:

[image]

[image]

The other one in the *UV Editor*. According to the docs, it "continuously unwraps the selected UV islands while transforming pinned vertices":

[image]

Comment: its a different uv unwrap. I don't know what the uv editor but even in the blender docs it's one of the only things it says on it. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/tool_settings.html#uvs

Comment: Ok I've edited, I'm going to look into the difference, the one you're looking for is the first one, it will change the UV map whenever you change the seams of the object

Comment: Great! some stuff seemed to have with 2.91 so im just trying to readjust.

Comment: I'll edit to explain the UV Editor Live Unwrap, I don't understand what it is